# error: cannot find symbol + in android for string concatenation

Tags: android

It is a bit weird error. So here is the screenshot of it.[image]

So it can not concatenate any string in my project with +. I tried everything possible to fix it. Invalidate cash, clean up the project. nothing works. It happenes everywhere I have used +. For example:

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + dbAdapter.getDatabaseName());
```

it gives me the error on this + sign as well.

I am using Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1. Compile SDK 31. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `db.execSQL(String.format("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s", dbAdapter.getDatabaseName()));`

Comment: What is wrong with +? It was working perfectly  fine. After updating my Android Studio all gets messed up

Comment: Maybe something to do with Java's pass-by-value vs pass-by-reference thing.

Comment: This problem occurs whenever I manipulate a SQLITE database, regardless of which Android Studio is utilized. The `String.format()` technique is quite helpful.

Comment: When we upgrade Android Studio, we must be aware of the JVM version we are using. Some APIs and plugins may be affected.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your codebase file encoding system is UTF-8 based.

You can find your encoding settings for your projects by clicking on **File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings.** Under "**Editor**" and "**File Encodings**" you can set IDE Encoding and Project Encoding to the same value to avoid those type of errors.

You can easily change your file encoding from the bottom of your Android Studio.

[image: You can easily find out on the bottom of your android studio]

[image: Or simply match your settings with the following screenshot and update your encoding system. Hopefully this will works.]

Or simply match your settings with this screenshot and update your encoding system from the settings. Hopefully this will work. Thanks.

Comment: A weird request, but could u share your theme?

Comment: Weird file encoding system occurs this type of error for me earlier. But this may not the actual cause. There may be other reasons like plugin issue or other studio settings issue. By the way, it's Tanne theme @MAshhal